# Fatal Error in WordPress WooCommerce Plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, fatal-error

I just downloaded the woocommerce plugin and was trying to add a new product but it crashed the website and now I am unable to login into my wp admin page or make any changes to the website. I also am not able to view the website when the URL is typed in. All that is seen on the website is:

> Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in
>   /home3/averykohhc/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-gateway-paypal-express-checkout/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-gateway-ppec.php
>   on line 231

Can someone please help me solve this problem? Since I cannot login into my WordPress account I can't post this on the forum to ask for help.

Thanks!!

Comment: Why cant't you contact the plugin developers?

Comment: I have but Im not a paying customer so I doubt they will pay notice to my note. Their website did say that they will not prioritise customers who are not paying.

Comment: Considering we can't see any of your code, or have no idea about this plugin, it's a long shot asking on here, when as you say you are able to contact developers. Your options are there, I would suggest waiting for a response back from them.

Comment: Via SSH, FTP, or control panel's file manager, access the `wp-content/plugins` folder and rename it to `wp-content/plugins-backup`. Then try to log back in to the site. This will deactivate all plugins and you will be able to log in. Then rename the folder back to its original name. And yes, contact the support for the gateway plugin.

Comment: woo commerce version  ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your site back then you just need to delete this woocommerce plugin file in public_html/wp-content/plugins/ after that you wont get any error message and your site will be back.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing this error in PHP v. 5.3.29 , apparently prior to PHP 5.5, empty() only supports variables and hence causes this error on earlier versions of PHP. I think it would be helpful if the FAQ mentioned PHP 5.5 or higher is required.